# Timing out tests in TestNG

Tags: java, multithreading, testng

Thanks to a library upgrade (easymock 2.2 -> 2.4), we're having tests that have started locking up. I'd like to have a time out on individual tests, all of them. The idea is to identify the locked up tests - we're currently guessing - and fix them.

Is this possible, preferably on a suite-wide level? We have 400 tests, doing this each method or even each class will be time consuming.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [suite tag](http://code.google.com/p/testng/source/browse/trunk/src/main/org/testng/xml/XmlSuite.java) can have the time-out attribute. This time-out will be used as default for all test methods.

This default time-out can than be overridden on a per test method basis.

Comment: We're using maven, so I had to find the relevant settings on the surefire plugin. Unfortunately, it's not telling us which test is dieing on?! Oh well, that'll be another question.

Comment: You can also add the timeout attribute to the <test /> element under a <suite />.  This coupled with includes / excludes within the <test /> element can allow you finer grained control.

Answer (score 2):

If the Suite level turns out to be the wrong approach (i.e. "too wide a net", because you end up marking too much methods with a timeout limit), you need to define a custom [IAnnotationTransformer](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#annotationtransformers)  which, for each illegible function, will give you the opportunity to modify a @Test annotation (with, for instance the [setTimout() method](http://code.google.com/p/testng/source/browse/trunk/src/main/org/testng/annotations/ITestAnnotation.java)).
(`setTimout(0)` cancels a timeout directive)

Answer (score 2):

Very late, but: running `jstack -l <PID>` will give you the stack dump, which you can inspect to find which calls are stuck.  You might want to sample a few times to be sure they're stuck.

Answer (score 1):

You can do a search and replace for "@Test" with "@Test(timeout=)"
Should work to find the locked up test and can be undone after that.

Comment: this not very DRY-friendly